# Static member variables in multithreading

Tags: c++, static-variables

As all of you know, despite how many objects instantiated, only one instance of static member variables are stored in the BSS segment. Accordingly, consider having some thread which instantiates a class with a static member variable and changes static member frequently; my question is whether the static member is thread-safe or not.

Comment: There's only one function even if it's non-static; static member functions are basically free functions using the class as their namespace. Problems arise if and when functions (members or not, static or not) concurrently write and (read or write) the *same objects*. That happens easily with static data members or global variables.

Comment: Note that in your scenario "having some thread which instantiates a class with a static member variable and changes static member frequently" there is no issue: Just the fact that you change a variable in code which runs in an explicit thread does not create concurrency issues, as long as it is always just *one* thread at a time. That is, for example, trivially true if you just run a single thread accessing that variable, explicit or not. Problems arise if you create more than one thread accessing the variable without due protection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables do not know anything about threads.  Class static member variables are not inherently thread-safe.  You might consider putting them in thread-local storage, or making sure the members' data structures are themselves thread-safe.

You also mentioned "static member functions" but those are immaterial to this question: it doesn't matter how you modify your static member variables, doing so is not inherently thread-safe, whether modified via static member functions, regular member functions, or non-member functions.

Comment: Oops, I meant variable. Thanks for your complete answer, by the way.